# Assert 2 lists with same objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have test project in Java. I have two different lists with some object. How I can assert, that this lists contains same objects (not only equals)?

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean assertSameObjects(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
    assertEquals(list1.size(), list2.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        assertSame(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the objects are located at different positions?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: As I understand the question, it deals with lists because the order is important.

Comment: I already implement as say @JB Nizet. I only had doubts, may be available more simple method

Comment: I still have one issue also. If I want compare two lists (equals), use: **assertEquals**. But I can also use **assertThat(..., is(...))**. Is this functions equivalent?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that List.equals() doesn't check for pointer equality but instead checks that the same items are in the same order in both lists. Writing a for-loop in unnecessary unless you need more checking on an item-by-item basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

- Iterate the lists (iteration on one being inside the other's).
- Compare entries using `==` because you want to compare references.
- Return `false` if an entry from outer list is not found in the inner list.
- Return `true` if the iteration of the outer list is complete (all object references in the outer list are also present in the inner list)